# Vertical line in XML for notification in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom notification XML file. I would like to draw a vertical line like the horizontal line in the below picture. I have been trying various ways couldn't achieve it. The orientation in xml from horizontal to vertical didn't help me.

Check my screenshot below:I would like to get the vertical line instead of the red line.

[image]

Tried the following code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#151515"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iconimagelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topTextlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1C1C1C"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alldismisslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dismissicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dismissicon"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dismissLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dismissText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/notificationdismiss"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Not sure where exactly I have to put the vertical line code.

Comment: basically you want UI like as you show in image right ???

Comment: Create an XML for background and use it in `iconimagelayout`

Comment: I dont quietly understand what you are asking, can you post an expected  and current have image.

Comment: @andruboy: Yes that is right..

Comment: @TheDevMan try my solution it is less complex and less view hierarchy you have taken unnecessary views and layout so i have removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey try this with **less** **`layout hierarchy`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#1C1C1C"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

<View
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:background="@color/GREEN" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topTextlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/your_color" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1C1C1C"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/GREEN" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alldismisslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dismissText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cancel"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/notificationdismiss"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried even yours, if I use View I am getting the same error...http://txs.io/NRS

Comment: I am not sure where the error is exactly. I am still getting android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.test.notificationApp, if I use View How to solve this?

Comment: I removed view and added LinearLayout. It worked fine.. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea on why View was giving me a problem?

Comment: which view youhave removed?? below title ??

Comment: All the three View's and replaced it with LinearLayout

Answer (score 4):

You can use following to create the vertical line.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="4dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"/>
```

Put this code after your first cancel imageview.So that your final code becomes

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iconimagelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="4dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topTextlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1C1C1C"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alldismisslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dismissicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dismissicon"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dismissLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dismissText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/notificationdismiss"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I use View for some reason I getting the following error: 

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.test.notificationApp: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.test.notificationApp user=UserHandle{0} id=100 tag=null score=20: Notification(pri=2 contentView=com.test.notificationApp/0x1090064 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x13 kind=[null]))

Answer (score 3):

Just use proper backgrounds and margin if you need

Here is the screenshot

[image]

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#151515"
android:baselineAligned="false"
>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topText"
        android:contentDescription="string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2E2E2E"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconimage"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#1C1C1C"
            android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dismissicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconimage"
            android:contentDescription="string/dismissicon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dismissText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dismissicon"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                 android:background="#2E2E2E"
                android:text="notificationdismiss"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iconimage"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dismissicon"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/topText"
                />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#151515"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconimagelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topTextlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#2E2E2E"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TITLE"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1C1C1C"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/alldismisslayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#2E2E2E"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dismissicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dismissicon"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dismissLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dismissText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/notificationdismiss"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Create one colored **vertical line 9 patch image**

then use that image in View in android xml file

Change your XML file like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#151515"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iconimagelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="icon"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

       <View
           android:layout_width="1dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/untitled" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topTextlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1C1C1C"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MESSAGE BODY"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alldismisslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E2E2E" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dismissicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="dismissicon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dismissLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dismissText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="notificationdismiss"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here in:

```
       <View
           android:layout_width="1dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/untitled" />
```

untitled is my 9 patch image.
9 patch image because it could be stretched as per the screen resolution